# PowerShell: Inventory Report Shows Blank Data for Installation Date of Every AD Domain Controller

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get the operating system installation date of every Active Directory (AD) Domain Controller of a single AD domain as part of an inventory report.  Thanks to [this article](https://www.powershellbros.com/list-domain-controllers-domain-report/), everything shown in the code block below will work in any AD environment.  The "Install Date" column though, shows blank data in the grid view.  To get the installation date it requires a PS-remoting session into each target Domain Controller. Not sure what I'm doing wrong with this after quite a bit of research, so posting here.

```
# Import AD module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
 
# Get your ad domain
$DomainName = (Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot
 
$AllDCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $DomainName | Select-Object Hostname,Ipv4address,isGlobalCatalog,Site,Forest,OperatingSystem
  
# Create empty DataTable object
$DCTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
      
# Add columns
$DCTable.Columns.Add() | Out-Null
$DCTable.Columns[0].Caption = "Hostname"
$DCTable.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Hostname"
  
$DCTable.Columns.Add() | Out-Null
$DCTable.Columns[1].Caption = "IPv4Address"
$DCTable.Columns[1].ColumnName = "IPv4Address"
                      
$DCTable.Columns.Add() | Out-Null
$DCTable.Columns[2].Caption = "isGlobalCatalog"
$DCTable.Columns[2].ColumnName = "isGlobalCatalog"
$DCTable.Columns[2].DataType = "Boolean"
  
$DCTable.Columns.Add() | Out-Null
$DCTable.Columns[3].Caption = "Site"
$DCTable.Columns[3].ColumnName = "Site"
  
$DCTable.Columns.Add() | Out-Null
$DCTable.Columns[4].Caption = "Forest"
$DCTable.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Forest"
  
$DCTable.Columns.Add() | Out-Null
$DCTable.Columns[5].Caption = "OperatingSystem"
$DCTable.Columns[5].ColumnName = "OperatingSystem"
 
$DCTable.Columns.Add() | Out-Null
$DCTable.Columns[6].Caption = "PingStatus"
$DCTable.Columns[6].ColumnName = "PingStatus"

$DCTable.Columns.Add() | Out-Null
$DCTable.Columns[7].Caption = "InstallDate"
$DCTable.Columns[7].ColumnName = "InstallDate"
 
# Loop each DC                        
ForEach($DC in $AllDCs)
{  
{
(invoke-command (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).ConvertToDateTime( (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate )) 
}
    $ping = ping $DC.Hostname -n 1 | Where-Object {$_ -match "Reply" -or $_ -match "Request timed out" -or $_ -match "Destination host unreachable"
    }
        switch ($ping)
    {
        {$_ -like "Reply*" }                          { $PingStatus = "Success" }
        {$_ -like "Request timed out*"}               { $PingStatus = "Timeout" }
        {$_ -like "Destination host unreachable*"}    { $PingStatus = "Unreachable" }
        default                                       { $PingStatus = "Unknown" }
    }  
    
         
    $DCTable.Rows.Add(  $DC.Hostname,
                        $DC.Ipv4address,
                        $DC.isGlobalCatalog,
                        $DC.Site,
                        $DC.Forest,
                        $DC.OperatingSystem,
                        $PingStatus,
                        $InstallDate
                              
                        )| Out-Null                          
}
 
# Display results in console 
$DCTable | Sort-Object Site | Out-GridView
 
#Creating head style
$Head = @"
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 8pt;
    }
  th, td, tr { 
    border: 1px solid #e57300;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    }
  th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #003366;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
  td {
    color: #000000;
     
    }
  .even { background-color: #ffffff; }
  .odd { background-color: #bfbfbf; }
  h6 { font-size: 12pt; 
       font-color: black;
       font-weight: bold;
       }
 
 text { font-size: 10pt;
        font-color: black;
        }
 }
</style>
"@
```

Comment: You never assign any to `$InstallDate` value, so that makes perfect sense :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Thanks, if I am following you correctly, I had tried that like this and it still showed blank data in the InstallDate column (I did not put that example into my original question):  *$InstallDate = (invoke-command (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).ConvertToDateTime( (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate ))*

Comment: You probably want `$InstallDate = Invoke-Command { (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).ConvertToDateTime( (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate) } -ComputerName $DC.Hostname` (you need curly braces around the command to execute, and you need to pass the DC's hostname so `Invoke-Command` knows where it's supposed to run)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Understood.  If I do like this:  *{
$InstallDate = (Invoke-Command {(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).ConvertToDateTime( (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate)} -ComputerName $DC.hostname)
}* the InstallDate column gets populated now, but with the data from the last DC checked.  Soooo close!

Comment: Take off the extra outer curly brackets. You are now defining that as scriptblock

Comment: @Theo - That worked!  Not sure who to give the credit to for this answer to now as you and MathiasR.Jessen deserve equal credit!  If either of you write your comment as an "Answer", I'll accept.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - wouldn't have gotten this working without both you and Theo.  Top notch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to:

- Make sure you actually execute the `Invoke-Command` statement on the target DC, by:

  - Surrounding the statement in `{...}` (to create a scriptblock, rather than execute locally)
  - Passing `-ComputerName $DC.Hostname` to `Invoke-Command`
- Assign the output from that call to `$InstallDate`

---

```
ForEach($DC in $AllDCs)
{
    $ping = ping $DC.Hostname -n 1 | Where-Object {$_ -match "Reply" -or $_ -match "Request timed out" -or $_ -match "Destination host unreachable"}
    switch ($ping)
    {
        {$_ -like "Reply*" }                          { $PingStatus = "Success" }
        {$_ -like "Request timed out*"}               { $PingStatus = "Timeout" }
        {$_ -like "Destination host unreachable*"}    { $PingStatus = "Unreachable" }
        default                                       { $PingStatus = "Unknown" }
    }  

    $InstallDate = if($PingStatus -eq 'Success'){
        Invoke-Command { (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).ConvertToDateTime( (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate )) } -ComputerName $DC.Hostname
    }
         
    $DCTable.Rows.Add(  $DC.Hostname,
                        $DC.Ipv4address,
                        $DC.isGlobalCatalog,
                        $DC.Site,
                        $DC.Forest,
                        $DC.OperatingSystem,
                        $PingStatus,
                        $InstallDate
                              
                        )| Out-Null
    # ...

}
```